# SQL Server 2008 Compiled TSQL Performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, compiled

What kinds of TSQL select statements (i.e. those starting from `select`) get benefited from compiling and what the advantages is provided by? By compiling I mean hosting select statements inside stored procedures.

I'm aware of other than performance advantages of stored procs (encryption, separation of concerns etc.), but I'm only interested in a performance aspect here.

Here's an example:

```
select t1.f1, t2.f2 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.pk = t2.fk
```

does/will the above sql run faster when it's factored as a stored proc rather than a command text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SQL Server optimizes and caches query plans based on the query text at the statement level, so generally, that statement will optimize the same whether in a stored procedure or not.

Now, there are other factors that can affect how that statement will be cached and optimized, and how a stored procedure might exhibit different performance characteristics (and use a different plan) than the same query outside of stored procedure. For example: SET settings. It is beyond the scope of your core question, but Erland's article, [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) is a fantastic and enlightening read.